# How to insert the last updated time-stamp in Jekyll page at build time?

Tags: jekyll

I would like to automatically insert a last updated timestamp (Not the `date` variable for the page) for each post at Jekyll build time, how to achieve that? I think I have to declare a variable but I am not sure how to assign the value to that variable.

For example, some time I update an old post, beside showing the post date, I also want to show the last update date.

I have tried `{{Time.now}}` but seems does not work.

Comment: You can use {{ site.time }}.

Comment: Thank! @DavidJacquel but what I really want is the post last update time now entire site update time.

Comment: That's what I thought. Now that I'm sure, I'll give you an answer.

Comment: Using `{{ site.time | date: '%A, %B %e, %Y' }}` worked for us to produce something like "Tuesday, April 11, 2023."

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The only collection that has a `modified_time` is `site.static_files`. Not so useful in our case.

One way to get the `last-modified-date` for posts in your Jekyll site is to use a hook ([documentation](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/#hooks)).

**_plugins/hook-add-last-modified-date.rb**

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :posts, :pre_render do |post|

  # get the current post last modified time
  modification_time = File.mtime( post.path )

  # inject modification_time in post's datas.
  post.data['last-modified-date'] = modification_time

end
```

It's now available in your posts as : `{{ page.last-modified-date }}`.
And you can format this date with the a date filter like `{{ page.last-modified-date | date: '%B %d, %Y' }}`. See the [Alan W. Smith excellent article on date Jekill Liquid date formating topic](http://alanwsmith.com/jekyll-liquid-date-formatting-examples).

**Important notice** : hooks are not working on Github pages.

Comment: I will try the plugin and thanks for the reminder (I will build the page before pushing to `gh-pages`).

Comment: An approach that does not require hooks is to save all your modification dates to ./_data/mtimes.json and then read that file from Jekyll.

Comment: Does the approach above work for Pages as well, instead of Posts?

Comment: @O0123 yes just change `:posts` to `:pages` on first line. You will then have à `page.last-modified-date` on any page.