# Last modified date hook to collection

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to apply [this hook](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36769049/3695939) to a custom collection:

**Hook**

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :docs, :pre_render do |post|

  # get the current post last modified time
  modification_time = File.mtime( post.path )

  # inject modification_time in post's datas.
  post.data['last-modified-date'] = modification_time

end
```

**Collection**

```
collections:
  docs:
    output: true
```

But right now the `last-modified-date` isn't being assigned.

I saw [on this comment](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/3834#issuecomment-152893751) that using the collection name should work.

I'm trying to order them by date and list them, but right now the field is coming out empty. All my fields on doc where created before setting up the hook, so maybe I need to do something for it to work.

Any ideas?
When does the hook run? (specially for pre-existent files)
How should I set it up to work with a collection?

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it is supposed to output some info in your console when you build or serve you jekyll site locally. This can help to debug.

#### _plugins/hook-docs-pre-render.rb

```
Jekyll::Hooks.register :docs, :pre_render do |post|

  # debug
  puts "Firing :docs, :pre_render from : " + File.basename(__FILE__) + " for : " + post.relative_path

  # get the current post last modified time
  modification_time = File.mtime( post.path )

  # debug
  puts "modification_time = " + modification_time.strftime('%A, %B %dth %Y at %l:%M%p')

  # inject modification_time in post's datas.
  post.data['last-modified-date'] = modification_time

end
```

**Note that hooks are not working on github pages.**

Comment: I'm not seeing anything on the console, so I guess something isn't working. Thanks for the github pages note, I'm hosting it somewhere else

Comment: Any repository url ? This can be helpful to debug.